# How does a query from the route handler and ember data communicate?

Tags: ember.js

How can a model() request find all data from 'rental' or ../models/rental.js?

```
model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('rental'); // 'rental' refers to ../models/rental.js?
}
```

A model() call will fetch data from /api/rentals defined in the adapter. But how does /models/rental.js talk to the data store and work alongside api calls?

In the quick start tutorial, it says

```
The store service is injected into all routes and components in Ember.
It is the main interface you use to interact with Ember Data.
```

I'm just trying to wrap my head around how the route handler and ember data communicate from a to z.

Comment: Read this ember [official guide section models](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/models/)

Comment: I'll re-read it again. Sometimes these things take a while to click for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the `store` for data for a `Model` from your Route's `model()` hook , it uses an `Adapter` to figure out how to make a call to the backend.  Adapters are usually configured for the whole application, but you can override adapters at the model level.

To quote [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/models/):

> Ember Data, included by default when you create a new application, is a library that integrates tightly with Ember to make it easy to retrieve models from your server as JSON, save updates back to the server, and create new models in the browser.
>
> Thanks to its use of the adapter pattern, Ember Data can be configured to work with many different kinds of backends. There is an entire ecosystem of adapters that allow your Ember app to talk to different types of servers without you writing any networking code.

When the HTTP response is received (assuming a REST adapter), Ember Data then uses a `Serializer` to parse the incoming payload.  The `Serializer` uses the definition of the record that is specified in the `Model`, then adds the records found in the payload to the `store`.

That's my high-level interpretation of how it works...  I would recommend the [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/) which take some time to go through but answer many common questions.

Hope that helps!